# Add Heading one time in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, html, foreach

I need to print heading div only one time. for example:

```
$cat_val=array(69,35,35,35,69)
{foreach from=$cat_val item=catval}
{if $catval=='69'}
<h1 class="page-heading">Products</h1>
{/if}
<li>some code</li>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: what language is that?

Comment: yes its using smarty.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that `if`. Just print your heading before your loop

```
<h1 class="page-heading">Products</h1>
$cat_val=array(69,35,35,35,69);
{foreach from=$cat_val item=catval}
    <li>some code</li>
{/foreach}
```

You were checking in the loop if value was 69 then print the heading, since 69 was the first value i assumed you made that `if` the way it is. But what about a situation where 69 is not the first value of your array? Then your heading will be messed up, that is why you don't need that `if`.

Comment: thanks for the reply but then what if i need both values to print in its own  div? for example:
<h1 class="page-heading">69</h1>
<li>some code</li>
<li>some code</li>
<h1 class="page-heading">35</h1>
<li>some code</li>
<li>some code</li>
<li>some code</li>

Comment: actually i need to use loop values in heading like:
<h1 class="page-heading">{$cat_val|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</h1>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{assign 'cat_val' ['69', '35', '35','35','69']}
<h1 class="page-heading">Products</h1>
{foreach from=$cat_val item=catval}
    <li>some code</li>
{/foreach}
```